# How do I escape an exclamation mark in bash?

Tags: bash

Sometimes I feel the urge to put some more expressiveness in my git commit messages. Unfortunately bash does not seem to like this.

```
iblue@silence ~/git/wargames $ git commit -m "Frustrating <insert object of frustration here>!"
-bash: !": event not found
```

Escaping with a backslash helps, but this includes the backslash in the commit message.

How do I escape the exclamation mark in bash correctly?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I mean, isn't it *correct* to have the exclamation mark in the commit message? If not, what do you want done with it?

Comment: OP probably meant that it includes the backslash in the commit message.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Exclamation mark is preserved literally when you include it in a single-quoted string.

Example:

```
git commit -m 'Frustrating <insert object of frustration here>!'
```

Comment: Downvote (with all respect): The Question is explicitly about escaping an exclamation mark. Your answer does solve the problem described above, is helpful as such, but it doesn't answer the question itself. I came here (using a search engine) with a slightly different problem and I need to really *escape* the exclamation mark (inside double quotes). Your workaround doesn't help me. If this question had a different title (e.g. "how to solve this exclamation mark problem") your answer would be perfectly fine. But as SO being a question & answer site, your answer misses the point.

Comment: I came with a question _"How to keep bash from putting its fingers into my arguments"_ and this answer helped me.

Answer (score 28):

Have a try this one

`git commit -m "Frustrating <insert object of frustration here>"'!'`

If in the middle of string then

`"hello"'!'"world"`

Answer (score 11):

Use single quotes instead to prevent expansion.

Comment: If it is part of a string you need to separate it by doing `" ' ! ' "` without the spaces I added

Answer (score 8):

In addition to using single quotes for exclamations, in most shells you can also use a backslash `\` to escape it. That is:
`git commit -m "Frustrating <insert object of frustration here>\!"`

However, I personally recommend [disabling bash expansion](https://superuser.com/questions/133780/in-bash-how-do-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark/133782#133782) in you shell by adding `set +H` or `set +o histexpand` to your `.bashrc` file.

If, like me, you never use bash expansion in your shell, disabling it will allow you to use exclamation points in any double-quote string - not only during your commits but for *all* bash commands.

Comment: I tried escaping `!` in a double quoted string with `\` while using `grep` recently in Bash. It didn't work for me, and I've confirmed it failed for the same reason that it failed for the OP.