# Why does bash prohibit a shell function named `df`?

Tags: bash, function, reserved-words, bash4

I am using `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

I have the following lines in one of my startup files:

```
df() {
        printf "Hello, world!\n"
}
```

When source that file, I get this error:

```
-bash: sh/interactive.sh: line 109: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: sh/interactive.sh: line 109: `df() {'
```

However, if I change the function name from `df` to `dir` or `ef` or `anything_else` I don't get the error.

I'm assuming that `df` is somehow a reserved word, but when I checked this [list of reserved words in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reserved-Word-Index.html#Reserved-Word-Index_rw_letter-D) I couldn't find it. (And I don't think it deserves to be one, anyway!)

So, can anyone shed some light on this? Why does bash prohibit me from defining a shell function named `df`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025114/how-do-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark-in-bash

Comment: @JoshLee: That's an issue, but it looks like something else is going wrong before parsing reaches that point.

Comment: That said, I can't reproduce the reported problem. The `!` causes problems, but naming a function `df` seems to work fine.

Comment: To diagnose: `type -a df`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you've previously defined an alias for this name. Aliases are simple string prefix substitutions, and therefore interfere with function definitions:

```
$ alias foo='foo --bar'
$ foo() { echo "Hello"; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

This is equivalent to (and fails with the same error as)

```
$ foo --bar() { echo "Hello"; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

To declare a function with a name that's been overridden with an alias, you can use the `function` keyword:

```
$ alias foo='foo --bar'
$ function foo() { echo "Hello, $1"; }
$ foo
Hello, --bar
```

Comment: I tried to verify this, in a different window, and realized you're entirely correct! I had been playing with df-as-alias before moving to df-as-function, and sure enough there was a legacy alias in the shell window where I was having the problem. Great catch, thanks!